# Problem with laravel 8 installing via composer

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php, mamp

When I have tried to install composer for laravel 8 on XAMPP localhost (on Macbook pro- on the path /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/the my project folder),
and when I have run first command:

- *php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"*

I have gotten this message in command line (terminal):
-bash: /Applications/**MAMP**/bin/php/**php7.4.16**/bin/php: No such file or directory

further to, I have found the following information:

*You need to install XAMPP for Windows, **MAMP for Mac OS** and Apache with PHP 5 on Linux.*

on :

https://nmgtechnologies.com/blog/web-application-php-laravel-framework.html

(***in requirements for Laravel section***)

For that, I have installed localhost MAMP, then I have tried installing composer on MAMP by running 4 commands that existing on https://getcomposer.org/download/.

Commands 1 & 2 were OK, but for command 3, it gave me errors as follow:

*The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
*error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Retrying...
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Retrying...
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.*

So, I opened **php** folder (*first one*) in the following path:
*/Applications/MAMP/bin/**php**/php7.4.16/bin/php*
and I found other versions expect required one (php7.4.16),so I installed it, but when I opened its folder, I found its subfolders are different of other versions, and it doesn't contain same folders (bin, php) in the path.
for that, the installing is failed (*command 3*)

NOW:

- Should I use and complete installing with **/MAMP**, could me to install on **XAMPP**
  also?
- how to solve this problem?

Note: I have currently PHP Version 8.0.9, and as show in installing path : **php7.4.16**, is the problem from here?

Thank you for my helping in advance.

Comment: I have installed from composer linking that in lavarel 7 section, because I didn't found in lavarel 8 section.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your last php was version 7.* and you installed 8.* now you want to use php version 8.*
for that you can add php installation path to your system environment paths.
MAMP and XAMP are offers a web server, database server, and php pre configured.
but if you dont want to use MAMP or Xamp applications you can download php from follwoing link and follow the documentation instructions for operating system.
https://www.php.net/downloads

Comment: No, I want to use MAMP or XAMPP.